# where is the file located in iphone after integrating a file to it via itune

Tags: iphone, ios

By enable the option called

> **Application supports iTunes file sharing**,

I can integrate a file ( example an image) into my device via iTune. My question is where is the location of that image in my device and are there any ways we can access it via xcode.
Please advice me on this issue if you have any ideas about this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app is sandboxed. That means it has it's own filesystem generated by xcode (/library /documents) relative to the app. Your files are probably on [yourapp]/documents.

Comment: can you specify about it...I am still lost how to locate the file

Comment: Sure, check [here](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files)

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode.... Organiser > Your Device > Applications > Click App > You can see the files in the sandbox